# ant (maven):run command in the background

Tags: java, maven, ant, javabuilders

I want to run an ant **background** command  which deletes something in the background later.

if I'm running it with
`<exec spawn="true">`.
The build still waits for the process to end.
How can we run the delete command detached from the main build so the build won't wait for it to end (in both linux and windows)?

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve? Apart from that If the delete is detached from the main build we can't be sure that if the build came to a particular state to create something it might be deleted in that particular time...so in the end it would fail the build?

Comment: I want to use this articale http://bosy.dailydev.org/2009/02/speed-up-your-maven-build-four-times.html which instead of cleaning the folder directly, it moves the folder and then at a later time it delete the folder on demand.
I want to make it automatically and silent in the background instead of on demand.

Comment: First about what kind of timing problem are talking about? How large is your build? How long does it take? How many modules? How many tests? On what platform do you build your java app? What kind of hardware are you using? (Currently I'm building a large application 1.5 million lines of code ca. 800+ modules in a single maven build within 6 minutes including 7000+ unit tests)? The referenced article is about 8 years old...are you using a repository manager ?

Comment: Furthermore a request for this exists a longer time: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MCLEAN/issues/MCLEAN-54 but there is not much attraction to this?

Comment: Please can you publish your `pom.xml` or at least the section containing the `<exec spawn="true">`?